# Several sql requests to retrieve data(hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, dao

Sorry for my English. Began to deal with javaee and do not quite understand how to make some operations. I have 2 tables **categories** and **posts** .In **posts** has fields **id**, **namecat** and **index**. In **posts** has fields **id**, **namePost**, **text**, **idCat**. If the table **category** index = 1. So all the posts that belong to this category must bring to the home page.In the request it will look something like this:

```
id = select * from category where index=1 //Here we learn how to id category i want displayed.
select * from post where idcat=id //and here all put
```

but I can not figure out how to do it in code. Here there:

```
  public Collection getPostFromCatId() {
            List<Category> category= null;
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                SQLQuery q = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery("
select * from category where index=1"); //get all category i want displayed. How to get here id and paste the following query?
                q.addEntity(Category.class);
                category= q.list();

            } catch(Exception e) { outputError(e);
            } finally{ closeSession(session); }
            return category;
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I understand, but if I do understand correctly, you want to get all the posts where post.idCat is equal to a value in the category table. If this is the case, you want to do a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). You can find an explanation of joins [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I suggest you retrieve your data in one query instead of two, like this:

```
select p.* from post p
join category c on c.id=p.idCat and c.index=1
```

And then in hibernate request you should use the Post entity, since you are querying posts, not categories

```
q.addEntity(Post.class);
```